# Sql - How to generate unique record based on column from mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have an mssql table with this format:

```
ID  |Code   |Name   |Date
1   |01     |A      |2011-01-01 00:01:23
2   |02     |B      |2011-07-01 00:01:23
3   |01     |A      |2011-05-01 00:01:23
4   |01     |A      |2011-07-01 00:01:23
5   |03     |C      |2011-02-01 00:01:23
6   |04     |D      |2011-01-01 00:01:23
7   |03     |C      |2011-01-01 00:01:23
8   |02     |B      |2011-01-01 00:01:23

I need to select unique code with with latest date as follows:

ID  |Code   |Name   |Date
1   |01     |A      |2011-07-01 00:01:23
2   |02     |B      |2011-07-01 00:01:23
3   |03     |C      |2011-02-01 00:01:23
4   |04     |D      |2011-01-01 00:01:23
```

How do I write an sql query to achieve this?

Comment: Seriously, I don't know why people would down-vote this!! I had tried different queries, and I needed a way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.code = t.code);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Very simple just used Group by Clause..

```
select ID,Code,Name,MAX(Date) as Date from TableName Group by Id,Code,Name
```

Another Way is CTE Function

```
With CTE AS
(
SELECT  row_number() over(partition by Code order by Code) rn
ID,Code,Name,MAX(Date) as Date
FROM TableName 
)

select ID,Code,Name,Date from CTE  where rn = 1
```

Comment: The first query will return with an error on microsoft sql server with something like: Column 'ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: @@osagie, sorry I have edited my answer ...You can also try the second query...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group BY` and Get the `MAX` Date.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Code), Code, Name, MAX(Date)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Code, Name
```

Comment: Hello @Angelo, I also need ID and Name as part of returned result.

Comment: Modified answer. I am assuming that the ID you require is like a row index counter (as the Id you have in the result set does not correlate to the data you provided above).

Answer (score 0):

Please put the table name at the place of "YourTable" and try below query.

```
SELECT ID,CODE,NAME,MAX(DATE)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID,CODE,NAME
ORDER BY CODE,NAME DESC
```

Comment: This isn't going to provide the results they are looking for. In fact from the sample data it will return every row.

Answer (score 0):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where code = t.code abd date > t.date
);
```

Or with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select t.id, t.code, t.name, t.date
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by code order by date desc) rn
  from tablename
) t
where t.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the same id's:

```
SELECT Id, Code, Name, [Date]
FROM
(
    SELECT *
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code, Name ORDER BY [Date] DESC, Id) AS Rn
    FROM yourtable
) q
WHERE Rn = 1
ORDER BY Id;
```

To get new id's:

```
SELECT 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX([Date]), Code, Name) AS Id, 
 Code, 
 Name, 
 MAX([Date]) AS [Date]
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Code, Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT tbl1.* FROM tbl1 WHERE tbl1.date = (SELECT max(tbl2.date) FROM tbl1 tbl2 WHERE tbl2.code = tbl1.code);
```